# Font 'rendering' issue in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debian, fonts, truetype-fonts, visual-studio-code

After installing Visual Studio Code (Version 1.17.2) x64 on Debian-Sid Xfce version 4.12.1 along with Openbox. I noticed these strange 'rendering' issues with fonts:

[screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQiar.png)

[screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2SGO.png)

[screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EurKp.png)

First thoughts were lack of dependencies, but did clean install a few times. The issue only exists in VSC other applications are fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download the libfreetype6 from Stretch from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libfreetype6/download), extract the libfreetype.so.6.12.3 file from the .deb and put that in the VSC dir (default: /usr/share/code). Create a symlink to it: `ln -s libfreetype.so.6.12.3 libfreetype.so.6` (or just rename it), and you're done.

Tnx to Alex V for the pointer to libfreetype6.

Answer (score 1):

Get the same rendering issue in Chromium. After downgrading libfreetype6 to stable version, issues were gone.
I do not know if VSC in Debian-Sid requires libfreetype6 debian-Sid version.

Hope that will help.

Comment: However, this breaks `libcairo2` and `libharfbuzz0b` so I might stick with using sublime instead of VSC. Thanks anyway!